# Why does PopSQL ask me to check the manual?

Tags: mysql, popsql

I'm currently learning SQL using the popsql ide. I'm trying to run the command to create a table but I keep gettting

```
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--auto increment automatically adds 1 to the primary key-- name VARCHAR(20) ' at line 2
```

What am I doing wrong? Below is the sql code

```
--writing table in all caps differentiates it from other phrases
--the keyword phrase NOT NULL indicates that the column has to have a value in it at every row
--the UNIQUE keyphrase indicates that the column values have to be unique 

CREATE TABLE student (
    student_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,--auto increment automatically adds 1 to the primary key
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    major VARCHAR (20) UNIQUE,
    age INT DEFAULT 'undecided', --the DEFAULT keyword will populate a particular row with phrase in quotes if there is no info entered
    PRIMARY KEY(student_id)
); 
--constraints are rules that we set in our db to control what happens to info.
--creating a rule such that a particular keyword should populate a row when no data is in it is a constraint  
DESCRIBE student;
--the keyword 'DROP' deletes any item that we specify--

DROP TABLE student;

--THIS LINE ADDS THE GPA COLUMN TO OUR TABLE--
ALTER TABLE student ADD gpa DECIMAL(3,2);

--this command displays the info that's currently in the table
SELECT * FROM student;

--INSERTING DATA INTO THE TABLE
--the order in which the tables were created should be the order in whcich they should be inserted into the table
--INSERT INTO student VALUES (2,'Rose', 'Chemistry',3.23);

--you can specify what values to add to the database if you don't have a particular key 
INSERT INTO student(name, major) VALUES('John', 'Chemistry');
```

Comment: Did you, at any point, consider following that advice? Programming is easier when you follow simple instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct: you should consult the manual when you are in doubt.

From [the MySQL documentation on comments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comments.html):

> From a `--` sequence to the end of the line. **In MySQL, the `--`  (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be followed by at least one whitespace or control character** (such as a space, tab, newline, and so on). This syntax differs slightly from standard SQL comment syntax, as discussed in Section 1.7.2.4, “'--' as the Start of a Comment”.

You did not do that, so your syntax is invalid.